# Problems with rendering of jquery tooltips on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm working [on a site](http://www.qualprnt.com/qp2txp) where there are popup windows on the header generated by Jquery Tools Tooltip (http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html). My problem with them is twofold:

1) In IE7/IE8, the popups are visible on page load, causing the header to break apart and scatter across the page. The CSS I wrote should be preventing this (it does in FF) but it's not working:

```
#container > section > header .trigger + *{
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
z-index:1000;
}
```

For reasons unknown, IE is perfectly happy if I wrap the elements beneath the element with class .trigger in a UL. This was the way I'd originally set up the HTML, but I ended up going with Jquery tabs and scrubbing all mentions of lists in the header from the CSS, so I can't figure out why that's working.

2) My second problem is that when the form in the popup under the "Write to Us" heading is submitted, the header disappears and the content container shifts. What should be happening is the "thank you" message should be loading in the same popup the contact form was in. As the form is being generated by a plugin in the CMS I'm using, I'd ideally like to solve this problem without having to figure out a way to have JS intercept the plugin's output, but if necessary I will.

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" id="zcrc4246f0a2add167f83d1d4084631a0b4" class="zemContactForm" action="/qp2txp/#zcrc4246f0a2add167f83d1d4084631a0b4">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="zem_contact_nonce" value="735c856baeffe5da43125cbf5a628084" />
<input type="hidden" name="zem_contact_form_id" value="c4246f0a2add167f83d1d4084631a0b4" />

<label for="Name" class="zemText zemRequired Name">Name</label><input type="text" id="Name" class="zemText zemRequired" name="Name" value="" maxlength="100" />

<label for="Email" class="zemText zemRequired Email">Email</label><input type="text" id="Email" class="zemText zemRequired" name="Email" value="" maxlength="100" />
<label for="Project" class="zemSelect zemRequired Project">Project</label>
<select id="Project" name="Project" class="zemSelect zemRequired">
<option>Branding</option>
<option>Print</option>
<option>Web</option>
<option>Interiors</option>

<option>Other (Please Describe)</option>
</select>
<label for="Message" class="zemTextarea zemRequired Message">Message</label><textarea id="Message" class="zemTextarea zemRequired" name="Message" cols="58" rows="8"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" class="zemSubmit" name="zem_contact_submit" value="Send" />


</div>
</form>
```

And the Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("header .trigger").tooltip({

position: 'bottom center',
offset: [30, -60],
relative: 'true',
delay: '70'

});

$("footer .trigger").tooltip({

position: 'top left',
offset: [-40, 100],
relative: 'true',
delay: '70'

});

});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem try `display:none;` instead of `left:-9999px;` for the second problem you will need to post the code.

Comment: I tried display:none, but it didn't make a difference in terms of rendering. I was avoiding using none for accessibility reasons, but it's not that huge of a deal either way.  The code is posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Trying and change your CSS + selector to apply the z-index. + selectors are buggy (like most useful CSS declarations) in the IE family.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: It's working in IE8 now; I set the z-index on the li element itself. IE7 is still showing the popups behind the content despite the z-index being set to 100000.

Comment: You want to apply the z-index to whatever is position:absolute; so by the looks of things in this case you want it on your <ul>. Ideally you could go .trigger + ul {z-index:1000;} If you are able to add a class to the <ul> and add the z-index that way.

Comment: z-index on .trigger + ul works in IE8 and FF, but still no dice in IE7. What really irks me is this is the first time I've run into issues with z-index; it was working in all browsers until I stripped the ULs from the nested divs. But I can't find anything in my code that would be affecting the z-index of the ULs in just IE7.

Comment: As for the header disappearing. On line 216 of your stylesheet remove the float:left; from this declaration : #container > section > header > div and debug back from there. By the looks of things some of your containers probably need hasLayout which can be accomplished by put overflow:hidden; on the parent of any node that has direct child elements that float.

Comment: Yeah if .trigger + ul is working in IE8 the only reason it is not working in 7 is because + selector is not supported. So try and add a class to the UL and apply the z-index that way.

Comment: Setting the class didn't work either. I'm actually using the + selector extensively in this stylesheet, and all other instances are working as expected except for this one. The only thing I can think of is a conflict with another plugin, but as it was rendering correctly until I stripped the ULs the first time, and as I've made no changes to any of the JS today, I'm not sure what plugin could be throwing it off.

Comment: Re: line 216, I actually do need the overflow on the parent element to be visible as the store hours are being positioned absolutely beyond the bounds of the div. If I set it to hidden, I lose the hours; setting it to auto generates scrollbars, which I definitely don't want. But you did inspire me to tinker with the header element a bit; it turns out that increasing its height to accommodate the overflow and setting the height of the divs to the header's original height does allow for the thank you text to appear without causing everything to implode on itself. Thanks!

Comment: Another Stack overflow question solved the z-index issue for me: I set the z-index on the header element itself rather than the div, and now IE7 is perfectly happy. I hadn't realized that IE was so finicky about stacking contexts, but I guess I shouldn't be surprised.